# scroll new ListActivity with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

**How to click on item that i can't see lit7.txt?**

I can't scroll MyListActivity with Espresso and click on particular item. I would like to click on lit7.txt item, but i can't see it on the screen. I need to scroll down. But how?

[screen image with MyListActivity(DirectoryViewer) and lit7.txt](http://s21.postimg.org/5gheji6pz/My_List_Activity.png)

I can click on "Browse..."

```
Espresso.onView(Matchers.allOf(ViewMatchers.withText("Browse..."))).perform(ViewActions.click());
```

I can click on histo2.txt

```
Espresso.onView(Matchers.allOf(ViewMatchers.withText("histo2.txt"))).perform(ViewActions.click());
```

**But how to click on item that i can't see lit7.txt?**

So, I loading my ListActivity(DirectoryViewer)

```
protected void onLoad(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DirectoryViewer.class);
        intent.putExtra(DirectoryViewer.ASSET_DIRECTORY_LOCATION, "books");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);}
```

DirectoryViewer is:

```
class DirectoryViewer extends ListActivity
...
    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String dirName = getIntent().getStringExtra(ASSET_DIRECTORY_LOCATION);
        List<ListItem> items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
        items.add(new BrowseListItem(getString(R.string.my_browse)));//Browse...
        items.add(new HeaderItem(getString(R.string.myItems)));//ITEMS
        AssetManager am = getResources().getAssets();//files
        try {
            String[] topLevel = am.list(dirName);
            for (String folder : topLevel) {
            ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, is this problem resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into the [onData method](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples) which allows you to interact with information in ListViews.

Comment: The question has too many code snippets. Use it and suggest the person where to replace/add the code clearly.

Comment: Problem was solved. I have used Android Device Manager->Connected Device->Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator and figure out what exactly i need to click. Code looks like: "onData(Matchers.allOf(Matchers.is(Matchers.instanceOf(FileListItem.class)))).atPosition(10).perform(ViewActions.click())". I have use onData as usggested above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will scroll the list view till 20th item is visible.

```
 onData(hasEntry(equalTo(ListViewSample.ROW_TEXT),is("List item: 20")))
        .check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
```